# How to decode an image string using base64 in command line?

Tags: command-line, batch

Say I have an image `image1.jpg`
I can encode it using `base64` tool :

```
myImgStr=$(base64 image1.jpg)
```

I tried to decode it using the following command:

```
base64 -i -d $myImgStr > image2.jpg
```

or

```
echo -n $myImgStr | base64 -d -i > image2.jpg
```

But in both cases I get the following error:

`base64: extra operand ‘/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/7QCEUGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAGgcAmcAFHNH’
Try 'base64 --help' for more information.`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The utility [`base64`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/base64.1.html) reads its input either from a file whose name is supplied as an argument, or from standard input. It never reads its input from a command line argument. In your case, to decode a string stored in a variable, you should supply the string on the standard input of `base64`.

If you are using Bash, you may use a here-string:

```
base64 -d <<< "$myImgStr" > image2.jpg
```

If your shell does not accept here-strings, you can always use:

```
echo "$myImgStr" | base64 -d > image2.jpg
```

(Note the doublequotes around `"$myImgStr"`. You should always doublequote variable expansions unless you have a good reason not to.)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to write. In the second version, it might be useful to emphasize how the variable is enclosed in double quotes (`"$myImgStr"`), which is necessary and missing in the failed attempts listed in the question.

Comment: Why you used `<<<` instead of `<<` in the first command?

Comment: @Navaro: `<<` and `<<<` are different things. `<<` introduces a here-document, and `<<<` a here-string. See [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html); search for `<<<`.

Comment: I think it is `-D` not `-d`

Comment: @LucasGoossen: [manual page for `base64`(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/base64.1.html).

Comment: @AlexP hmm... the man page on macOS 10.13.6 has `-D` and I just noticed we are on "Ask Ubuntu" ha!